# How do I start erl.beam file automatically on Linux system start?

Tags: shell, erlang

I've built Erlang,yaws and php into a single folder on Linux obviously it is a web server and the only way I can start this server is by following these two steps Opening a shell and entering the following commands.

Step 1.`$erl` 
Step 2.`1>prog:start().`

So, I need it to run automatically upon Linux operator system start.

Answer (score 3):

The `erl` command has many possible arguments and it also may depend on the Linux distribution but some broad strokes:

You can use the `-detached` argument to `erl` in order to run the VM detached. Also the `run` argument will call a function as soon as the VM starts up. So running the following line on your Linux command line should do the Erlang part:

```
erl -detached -run prog
```

Notice that `run` will by default call the `start` function of the prog module.

What's left is to make the OS call this command on start-up. If you are using a systemd system, you can create [Systemd Units](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) and enable them.